# Thunderbird api to send a mail via Java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, thunderbird

I have been using Java mail API to send mails generated through the Java program. What I want to do now is to send a mail through Thunderbird mail client so that the mail get saved to the sent items folder of the user and the user can resend a mail if it has failed.

I also would like to know if it's possible to get a delivery report in the Java mail API.

### Edit

I found out that our mail server is POP3 and it doesn't store mail. So is it a good idea to send another mail to the sender as well and define a rule that categorize those messages?

Answer (score 0):

even if you send it with the java mail api (well gmail at least), you will still be able to see in the sent folder using thunderbird. as a matter of fact, 5 minutes ago, I saw this using a website that I build. I am sending emails using Java API, and when I check the send folder I can see them.

Answer (score 0):

The InBox / Outbox in Thunderbird are normally mapped ti your IMAP-Account. The IMAP-Account is set on a mail server. All your mails and folders are stored on that mail server. the client (Thunderbird) only shows the contant from the server. By remote calls (IMAP-protocol) you can create/delete/edit/move folders and mails on the server. Sending a mail is not part of IMAP. Here you use the SMTP-Protocol. When you configure a mailaccount in Thunderbird you must configure IMAP & SMTP. When you send a mail Thunderbird does the following steps:
- Send Mail by SMTP-Protocol
- Create Mail in Outbox by IMAP-Protocol

SMTP & IMAP are totally different. But if you want to send a mail and see this mail in your outbox you must use both. You can program the same workflow with the java mail api.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, you are looking for a way to trigger mail sending via *Mozilla Thunderbird* from a Java program (an external program / software running on the same local machine).

You can achieve that via different methods:

- calling the *Thunderbird* binary with [command-line arguments](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_%28Thunderbird%29)
- via SimpleMAPI, which Thunderbird [supports](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Calling_Thunderbird_from_other_programs)
- via XPCOM, also [built into](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Calling_Thunderbird_from_other_programs) Thunderbird

What you won't be able to achieve easily is getting feedback from Thunderbird about the outcome of triggering / prompting the user to send a mail. But you could achieve that by using more difficult ways of integrating Thunderbird with your external software:

- read and parse the actual MBOX inbox / mail sent / profile files in a user's profile. "using the X-Mozilla-Status headers (you could) figure out if a message is a new message (etc). A mbox file is essentially just a flat text file that has a seperator between the messages" (parentheses by me, [source](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Calling_Thunderbird_from_other_programs))
- Write a bridging WebExtension *Thunderbird* Add-On that integrates in some way with your software. An extension has, via *Thunderbird*'s [WebExtensions API](https://webextension-api.thunderbird.net/en/latest/), essentially a hook for every feature *Thunderbird* has and your code Add-On could expose these internals in some way to your software.

AFAIK and sadly *Thunderbird*, as it ships, exposes no API or similar interface out of the box.